# Circa 1980s British TV series involving teens/young adults in a techno-spy mystery

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to identify a British import on Canadian TV I remember watching around the 1980s. The series involved a group of teens or young adults caught up in intrigue surrounding some sort of nefarious plot which I think concerned nuclear missiles. The one detail I clearly remember is the opening or closing title sequence in which the theme music played over footage of a missile launch, I think from a submarine. [Codename Icarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codename_Icarus) seems like it might be what I am looking for except that the music (where it can be heard) on YouTube clips doesn't match. The music played on the YouTube clips sounds like an excerpt of a classical piece, but the music as I remember it was more contemporary and energetic, and I assume would have been composed for the show.

Comment: Rocket launches could be seen in Damnation Alley https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmui7WAO-mQ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see any science-fiction or fantasy element which would make this "techno-spy" show on-topic per [the FAQ on occasional SF elements](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/98028) (including, but not limited to, spy stuff).

Comment: @Jenayah Having identified the title, found a wikipedia page for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doombolt_Chase where it is categorized as sci-fi, I think because plot points involve advanced technologies that were non-existent in its day

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds vaguely like [The Doombolt Chase](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0166038/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), where a bunch of teens strive to clear one of their Dad's name of some trumped up charge I don't remember the details of, all while on the run from shadowying forces.  It's a bit scifi, as it involves some kind of fictional super weapon, but it is super low budget so you only see it in action once. The opening credits has a submarine missile launch.  I was made to watch it at school for some reason in the 90s in Canada.  Check out the first episode [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd_89wFDddw), and see if the opening credits match your memory.